# Force loading of extra-lazy assoc in Doctrine2 for unit testing (no DQL)

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, lazy-loading

I'm running into a small problem with unit testing in Symfony2. I have a few associations marked as extra-lazy, which is fine.

However, when testing them, they don't get loaded (of course), which means the assertions fail. I'm not doing any DQL, just entity testing.

How can I tell Doctrine to ignore the extra-lazy tag for unit testing ALONE ?